# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: [...] maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven

### Initial Situation

I am getting the following warning when working with the demo spring boot project:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
>   (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

Any ideas how to resolve this?
I am behind a corporate proxy and have had to set proxy settings in various config files.

### Update

I also see the following:

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom

Comment: It is not an error, it is only a warning in eclipse

Comment: @Jens how do I resolve/fix this warning?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html